# Switch to the root file system in BusyBox using a disk image with the file system inside

Tags: linux, busybox

My disk image is downloaded from [ubuntu-22.04-minimal-cloudimg-amd64-root.tar.xz](https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/minimal/releases/jammy/release/ubuntu-22.04-minimal-cloudimg-amd64-root.tar.xz) using the following commands:

```
fallocate -l 16GiB rootfs.img
mkfs.ext4 rootfs.img

mkdir rootfs
sudo mount -o loop ./rootfs.img ./rootfs
sudo tar xf ubuntu-22.04-minimal-cloudimg-amd64-root.tar.xz -C rootfs
sudo umount rootfs
```

After creating the `init` file in the `_install` directory, I did

```
find . | cpio -H newc -o | gzip > initramfs.cpio.gz
```

then I used the following QEMU command to try to boot:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -nographic -kernel /path/to/bzImage -initrd initramfs.cpio.gz -append "console=ttyS0" /path/to/rootfs.img
```

My `init` file currently looks like this (it's not going to find `rootfs.img` since it's too big to be put inside the .cpio file):

```
#!/bin/sh
set -ex
exec switch_root rootfs.img /sbin/sh
```

I'm not sure how I should specify the parameters for `switch_root` in order for it to use the `/path/to/rootfs.img` I provided in the QEMU command.

I tried to follow [this](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Custom_Initramfs#Init), but I think I should use the `rootfs.img` instead of `/dev/sda1`. Again, I'm not sure how to do it.